# Create different variables through a loop and execute a set of commands

Tags: python, loops, variables, for-loop, dictionary

I am new to python and appreciate if someone can help me out with this.

I want the user to create certain number of dictionaries. Then for each dictionary I want execute specific commands. I am looking for something like this.

```
for i in range (1, user_value):    
    file_i = dict()    #creates a new dictionary      
    print ('file'+i+'is created')        

exit()
```

At the end of this code, I should be able to access all the dictionaries which have been created. 
Thanks.

Comment: Once you `exit()`, you can't

Comment: Is there any reason you're not keeping your dictionaries in a list?